# Binding list collection to a list view

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list of objects and I would like to bind them to a list view with the use of data templates (one way binding). Currently, the list view does not show anything and I am new to this and I do not have any idea where the issue lies.

This is my object class

```
public class CategoryObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string CategoryObjectInstance;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my XAML Code for the list view

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="ListView1" Margin="10,0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=CategoryObject.CategoryObjectInstance, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is my code to input the itemssource

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        List<CategoryClass.CategoryObject> newCategoryObjectList = new List<CategoryClass.CategoryObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            CategoryClass.CategoryObject newCategoryObject = new CategoryClass.CategoryObject();
            //set arbitarily value 
            newCategoryObject.CategoryObjectInstance = i.ToString() + i.ToString() + i.ToString() + i.ToString() + i.ToString();
            newCategoryObjectList.Add(newCategoryObject);
        }

        //to debug
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(newCategoryObjectList.Count.ToString());
            messageDialog.ShowAsync();

        ListView1.ItemsSource = newCategoryObjectList;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? In addition, how/can data context be used to accomplished this? thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems here:

- the first main problem is that you have the wrong path in binding in XAML, it should be:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoryObjectInstance, Mode=OneWay}" />
  ```
- the second main problem is that you should bind to property - without this it also won't work
- and you are defining `OnPropertyCanged` but you are not using it (this is not so important now, but further changes won't dispaly in the List). Taking into account this point and above one, it should look like this:

  ```
  public string categoryObjectInstance;
  public string CategoryObjectInstance
  {
      get { return categoryObjectInstance; }
      set { categoryObjectInstance = value; OnPropertyChanged("CategoryObjectInstance"); }
  }
  ```
- but this above will only help once 'CategoryObjectInstance' changes, it won't help you when you add/remove items later, I would advise to use *ObservableCollection* instead of a *List*

Also I see that you use *MessageBox* for debugging which is not suitable for this, try to use:

```
//to debug
Debug.WriteLine(newCategoryObjectList.Count);
```

Open *Debug->Output window* in Visual Studio - you will see it there. If you were using it before, you could have seen your previous problems.

Comment: thank you so much, it works! I am definitely new to this, and would like to use the most "elegant" method to code without many little hacks along the way.

Comment: @user776914 You are welcome, I've also added information about better debug method that *MessageBox* - try to use it, it will help you much more.

Comment: may I ask how should I implement the OnPropertyChanged and use it correctly to update the listview? In addition, regarding the observablecollection, do I use it in the same way as a list and it will update the listview when items are added/removed?

Comment: @user776914 *ObservableCollection* will manage addition/removal operation on your collections - it will automatically inform your *ListView* and update it (make a shor example - move your `newCategoryObjectList` to main class (make it *ObservableCollection*) then upon button click add a new item - you should see it on the screen. As for OnPropertyChanged - it will update UI when the value of an item changes, make second button and put there `newCategoryObjectList[0].CategoryObjectInstance = "my new value";`. You should see it updated on the screen after button click.

Comment: I have managed to implement the observable collection and now it works! thanks for pointing this out now as I'm rather sure I will meet with this issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

DataContext already set to the object in the list. Try this:

```
Text="{Binding CategoryObjectInstance, Mode=OneWay}" />
```